# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object DrivingScript.Update ERROR

Tags: unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception, unityscript

I'm trying to make working keys to my car in my project but when i try to reference another script i get an error saying:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   DrivingScript.Update () (at Assets/Car/Trying To Make Custom Car/DrivingScript.js:21)

I've tried to look it up but couldn't find the problem if you can please help.

```js
 var Car : Transform;
 var player : Transform;
 var exitPoint : Transform;
 var tentplayer : Transform;
 var campfire : Transform;
 var doorTriggerLeft : Transform;
 var PlayerCamera : Camera;
 var CarCamera : Camera;
 var isPlayerVisable : boolean;

private var invScript : Inventory;

  function Start () {
  
  invScript = GetComponent(Inventory);
  
  }
  
  
  function Update (){
     if (CarCamera.enabled == false && invScript.LetDrive == true)
     {
     if (Input.GetKeyDown("r")&& isPlayerVisable){
         //Make player invisable and still standing
         player.gameObject.SetActiveRecursively(false);
         player.gameObject.active = false;
         // Parent player to ExitPoint
         player.parent = exitPoint.transform;
         player.transform.localPosition = Vector3(-1.5,2,0);
         //Parent playerParent to car
         exitPoint.parent = Car.transform;
         exitPoint.transform.localPosition = Vector3(-0.5,2,0);
         // Enable car as controllable object
         GameObject.Find("CarJeep").GetComponent("Car").enabled = true;
         PlayerCamera.enabled = false;
         CarCamera.enabled = true;
     }
     }
     else
     {
         if (CarCamera.enabled == true)
         { if (Input.GetKeyDown("r")){
             // Make Character visable again.
             player.gameObject.SetActiveRecursively(true);
             player.gameObject.active = true;
             // PUT CAFTABLE ITEMS HERE\/ \/ \/
             campfire.gameObject.SetActiveRecursively(false);
             tentplayer.gameObject.SetActiveRecursively(false);
             // PUT CRAFTABLE ITEMS HERE ^^^^
             // Unparent Player from everything.
             player.transform.parent = null;
             // Parent Exit Point to Door Trigger.
             exitPoint.parent = doorTriggerLeft.transform;
             // Disable car as a controllable
             GameObject.Find("CarJeep").GetComponent("Car").enabled = false;
             PlayerCamera.enabled = true;
             CarCamera.enabled = false;
         }
     }
    }
 }
 
 function OnTriggerEnter(Player : Collider) {
     isPlayerVisable = true;
 }
 
 function OnTriggerExit(Player : Collider) {
     isPlayerVisable = false;
 }
```

Comment: NullReferenceExceptions are always caused by the same thing, and always solved the same way: make sure your objects aren't null when you try to dereference them.

Comment: In your case, line 21 is `if (CarCamera.enabled == false && invScript.LetDrive == true)`.  So either `CarCamera` is null or `invScript` is null.

Comment: how should i properly reference a different int. for a different script because i used someone elses script and they referenced the script no problem but when i tried to copy the same things it didn't work

Comment: That's the risk you take when you use code that you don't understand.

Comment: Since Stack overflow doesn't have line numbers, and you probably don't copy the whole file anyway, it would be nice if you added a comment on the line that the error is happening on in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't set up CarCamera property in the editor and left it null, while this script relies on it being set up.